# How to random score when custom score is applied on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

On elasticsearch, first, I want to have [custom score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score) based on document field value and then [randomize scores](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html) which have same scores.

This is the simplified version of a query that I request from elasticsearch:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "return _score * doc['myCustomField'].value;"
          }
        }
      ],
      "function_score": {
        "random_score": { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response I got from this request is:

> "type": "parsing_exception", "reason": "failed to parse
>   [function_score] query. [you can either define [functions] array or a
>   single function, not both. already found [functions] array, now
>   encountering [function_score].]",

How to random score when custom score is applied?

Comment: If your custom_field is of natural values, you can simply add `Math.random()` at the end of scripted query.  The second`function_score`s should be defined in a `query context`